# Использование сервисов в android с mvp

Tags: android, архитектура, mvp

Как я понял, `mvp` предполает, что в `presenter` логика взаимодействия `view` и `model`. Откуда должен происходить запуск сервиса? Или может для взаимодействия с сервисами я выбрал не тот паттерн?

Answer (score 0):

Если речь об `MVP`,  `Service` необходимо стартовать из `Presenter`. (`View` не должна знать о его существовании, она должна только отображать данные по командам, которые летят от `Presenter`)

Для старта `Service`, необходим именно `applicationContext` (который живёт весь цикл приложения и не привязан к `Activity`), по этой причине, можно смело его инжектить в `Presenter` c помощью того же [Dagger2](https://github.com/google/dagger) и не бояться утечек памяти.

Comment: А не нужно разделять андроид классы и Ява классы? Вроде как в презентере не должно быть андроид зависимостей, а так там появляется контекст. А если например нужно сделать asynctask, в импорте добавится этот класс.

Comment: Тут палка  о двух концах. С одной стороны, нужно стремиться к тому, чтобы было так. С другой стороны, если использовать `AsyncTask` во `View` слое, то это будет явное нарушение, т.к. `view` будет знать о том, что что-то происходит не в ui-потоке. (Например, http-запрос).
И таких моментов будет очень много (например, то же получение координат). И от  `MVP` мало что останется, если так делать.
Смело используйте андроид-классы в `Presenter`, которые не требуют `context` от `Activity`

Comment: А что если в интерфейс взаимодействия view и презентера добавить ещё interface context. И тогда по идее не нужен будет импорт контекста, а во view его просто наследовать

Comment: Немного не понял Вашу идею. `view` Вы же дёргаете только из презентера (сам интерфейс, имею в виду). 
Полностью от импортов Android-классов Вы не избавитесь в любом случае.

Comment: Вот к примеру интерфейс: 
'public interface MVPmain {
    interface view {
       }
    interface presenter {
    }
}'
и добавить сюда еще и interface context, а в активити implements MVPmain.context

Comment: На мой взгляд, гораздо проще и чище для данных целей использовать паттерн `DI` , в частности одну из его реализаций - `Dagger2`. 

Приведите полный код: `Fragment/Activity`, `View`, `Presenter.` , т.к. Вашу идею я всё равно не до конца понял.

Comment: https://github.com/Anton-Kapustin/integrate/tree/rc2/app/src/main/java/com/dev/toxa/integrate/FragmentListServers
   например